# GCP - HTTP(S) Load Balancer L7 Backend Bucket Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have just migrated from the HTTP(S) L7 Load balancer (Classic) to the new HTTP(S) L7 load balancer.

I currently have two backend services working fine, and I am looking at creating two backend buckets - however I am getting an error when creating them.

If I select **simple host and path rule** and specify the host, path and backend bucket - it works fine.
[image]

However, if I specify advanced host and path rule, and supply the following configuration:

```yaml
defaultService: projects/MY_PROJECT/global/backendBuckets/my-backend-bucket
name: matcher2
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /
  priority: 0
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/MY_PROJECT/global/backendBuckets/my-backend-bucket
      weight: 100
```

I am getting this cryptic error

```
Invalid value for field 'resource': '{ "name": "my-loadbalancer", "hostRule": [{ "host": ["myhost.com"], "pathMatcher": ...'. Invalid resource: URL_MAP/ID.my-loadbalancer
```

Has anyone come across this issue before? I am getting this even though I am creating a new backend bucket. I also tried using the old backend buckets I had created with the classic load balancer, and still I am getting this error?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue by providing the following configuration `defaultService: projects/MY_PROJECT/global/backendBuckets/my-backend-bucket name: matcher2` I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work with the advanced host/path routing - which is a shame because I want to server different buckets based on production/development environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concern is actually feasible just using a different yaml, I believe what you have tried is the yaml from code guidance under load balancer routing. I also tried to use the code guidance but I am having an error message wherein load balancer is not created.

I used the [url maps documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#example_url_map_workflow_with_an) as a guidance and came up with this configuration and it worked using the advanced host and path.

```
name: video-matcher
pathRules:
- paths:
  - /video/hd
  - /video/hd/*
  service: projects/project id /global/backendBuckets/bucketname
```

Comment: Oh man, you're a legend! Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.